# Getting youtube data with python

Tags: python, xml, youtube

How would I get the url with the most views in youtube? Here is the link I am using, "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=gangnam%20style"

It returns xml data, how would I get certain elements of this? is their any module I could use to return the gdata link to go to the most viewed video? any help would be appreciated thank you. My problem is I do not know how to get certain elements is why I'm asking and thank you ahead of time.

Edit:
   Thank you everyone that answerd after about an hour or so on google I found a good way to do it but I appreicate all of you suggestions, but in a few hours when I can answer my own question I'll post it

Comment: Asked this question about a year ago. To anyone reading this if you add  a &v=2&alt=jsonc to the url it returns json serializable results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

For example, following code prints titles, view counts:

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.parse('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=gangnam%20style')
root = tree.getroot()
nsmap = root.nsmap
nsmap['xmlns'] = nsmap.pop(None)
for entry in root.findall('.//xmlns:entry', namespaces=nsmap):
    title = entry.find('xmlns:title', namespaces=nsmap).text
    view_count = entry.find('yt:statistics', namespaces=nsmap).get('viewCount')
    print(u'{}  {}'.format(title, view_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at libraries that parse XML for you to retrieve the node you want.

Take a look at

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

It starts off with a good example on how to do this. (country_data.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Python contains several xml parsers.
Take a look at the python standard library documentation.
If you're using python2 that's here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html

The various parsers differ in their complexity, so experiment with each find the one that suites your taste.
I prefer elementtree for a simple xml structre.
See the tutorial here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial